# Smooth Progress bar with only WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, custom-controls

I really didn't found something useful related to this topic.

Let's say I define a custom ProgressBar as a UserControl:

```
<ProgressBar x:Class="Views.Controls.ProgressBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Views.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Value="50">
</ProgressBar>
```

I want to make the progress bar animating smooth. I found some solutions doing this with background code in the control itself. As of MVVM this is definetly not how to handle this. 
The main goal would be to handle this directly in the xaml triggering the Value property value change and then starting a Animation. But as I already mentioned I couldn't find any useful resource for this.

After following the instructions of [this](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Animating_when_Data_Changes_Part_II.aspx) link but the bar doesn't fills up. My code:

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.Controls.ProgressBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KBSLauncher.Views.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Controls:MetroProgressBar x:Name="progressBar"/>
</UserControl>
```

Background code:

```
public partial class ProgressBar: UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(ProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(0d, ValueChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(ProgressBar));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(ProgressBar));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsIndeterminateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsIndeterminate", typeof(bool), typeof(ProgressBar));


    [Positive]
    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (double) GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    [StrictlyPositive]
    public double Maximum
    {
        get
        {
            return progressBar.Maximum;
        }

        set
        {
            progressBar.Maximum = value;
        }
    }

    [Positive]
    public double Minimum
    {
        get
        {
            return progressBar.Minimum;
        }

        set
        {
            progressBar.Minimum = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsIndeterminate
    {
        get
        {
            return progressBar.IsIndeterminate;
        }

        set
        {
            progressBar.IsIndeterminate = value;
        }
    }

    public ProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void ValueChanged (DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ProgressBar control = (ProgressBar)sender;
        control.ValueChanged();
    }

    private void ValueChanged()
    {
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.To = Value;
        animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Value * 2));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, progressBar);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(ValueProperty));
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(animation);
        sb.Begin();
    }
}
```

Comment: `DoubleAnimation` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Not really sure what "make the progress bar animating smooth" part means. Are you just trying to animate the value between your set min/max to make the progress bar fill or what?

Comment: No. Let's say I have the progress bar and the Value property has the value 30. Then I change this value to 90. Normally the progress bar would just change the progress directly. I want that the progress bar changes it's progress smoothly from 30 to 90 in a given amount of time.